# angular, trying to initialize values and realize better Angular karma :)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Check out this fiddle, trying to initialize the Login email, it's not and the javascript alert is not called, what am I missing?

```
<script>  
  var theApp = angular.module('theApp',[]);
  alert("I am here");
  $scope.email = "test@test.com";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r12un8ao/

Comment: you can't access scope outside the controller, angular basic are controllers and DI

Comment: sorry for the newbie stuff

Comment: That's not quite true, you can access scope of any Angular DOM element by $('...').scope() but is it the angular way of doing stuff? most certainly no. If you are the newbie always stick to Angular way: define your controllers and access scope through the injected $scope in controller. However if you have a legacy jQuery app hybrided with AngularJS you still can access the DOM's scope by $('...').scope

Comment: got it working, was a problem with scope/bootstrapping and a typo, have a better understanding such now, thanks for the tips!

Does anybody have a resource for documenting the technical details of how a component like Angular gets bootstrapped into the browser?